# vs code always changes authorization settings on startup

Tags: linux, git, docker, visual-studio-code, ssh

I use ssh to login to the remote linux host through vs code, and use the docker plugin to develop the container on the remote host. My local host is windows10. Remote host is ubuntu20.04

1. I configured git credential by the following command in terminal

```
git config --global credential.helper store
git config --system credential.helper store
```

[image]

2. Restart vs code and review git credential settings,it changed by vs code

[image]

How can I prevent vscode from automatically modifying the git credential configuration?

I have set disabling use of authentication in vscode as shown below
[image]